# Supressing 'File Created' output on 'create pfile' command in SQL*Plus

Tags: perl, sqlplus

I'm using a Perl script to run SQL*Plus and then sending a command to the program to create a pfile from the SP file. I want the command to run without outputting anything to the terminal. Running sqlplus in silent mode (`sqlplus -s`) suppresses most of the terminal output when calling sqlplus, but creating the pfile still outputs a 'File created' to the terminal regardless. How can I suppress this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `set feedback off` will suppress the 'File created' output in the terminal. If you are running a SQL script when calling SQL*Plus, adding that line before the `create pfile` line will suppress the output as well.